# How to change session.gc_maxlifetime?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, session, server, phpmyadmin

After setting `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 604880;` for phpMyAdmin, I'm getting the following warning in phpMyAdmin:

> Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than cookie
>   validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will
>   expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin.

Where do I have to set `session.gc_maxlifetime`? Is `/etc/php5/php.ini` the right place for it? Because `nano /etc/php5/php.ini` shows me a blank file. What's the right syntax to set `session.gc_maxlifetime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `phpinfo()` (in a browser), the output from that will have a setting: `Loaded Configuration File` that shows the path to the php.ini file that was used (see below). That will be the file to edit.

[image]

The setting in the file is a simple number/value change. Search the file for `session.gc_maxlifetime` as there is other information above that variable in the file.